# I'm a little confused with mysqli_insert_id

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the last id to add to another field in my database, but I don't know how to do it? this is my code:

this is my class connection

```
 class Connect{
 public static function conx(){
     $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "0804", "jjuridico");
     if(!$db){
         die("Mysql dice: ".mysqli_connect_error());
         exit();
     }
     return $db;
 }
 public static function Script_db($sql){
     $res = mysqli_query(Connect::conx(),$sql);
     return $res;
 }
```

}

and this

```
class Trabajo{
//variables
private $clientes = array();
public function agregar_cliente($name,$last_name,$apodo,$cedula,$email,$contacto,$direccion,$provincia,$municipio,$telefono,$trabajo,$celular,$estado,$lugar_trabajo,$dir_trabajo){
    //print_r($_POST);
    $date = date("Y/m/d");
    $res = Connect::Script_db("INSERT INTO cliente(nombres,apellidos,apodo,email,contacto,direccion,provincia,municipio,telefono,trabajo,celular,estado_civil,lugar_trabajo,direccion_trabajo,created_at) VALUES ('$name','$last_name','$apodo','$email','$contacto','$direccion','$provincia','$municipio','$telefono','$trabajo','$celular','$estado','$lugar_trabajo','$dir_trabajo','$date')");
    echo "New record has id: " . mysqli_insert_id(Connect::conx);
    //header("location: vista_cliente.php?msg=Usuario insertado correctamente");
}
```

}

I'm using mysqli_insert_id(Connect::conx)
but the result is 0

Comment: Does the 'cliente' table have an AUTO_INCREMENT field?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to call "mysqli_insert_id()" with the connection variable as an argument:

```
$insert_number = mysqli_insert_id(Connect::conx());
```

or in an object oriented fashion:

```
$insert_number = Connect::conx()->mysqli_insert_id();
```

For more information, take a look at the function documentation here:
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Let me know if you need any help with this.

Comment: thanks men, but im still getting 0 when i use this $insert_number = mysqli_insert_id(Connect::conx()); and nothing when i use this $insert_number = Connect::conx()->mysqli_insert_id();.... im thinking i can do something like this $last_id = SELECT * FROM cliente order by id desc; but lol.. that will be a bad practice...

Comment: Does the cliente table have an AUTO_INCREMENT column? If not, the mysqli_insert_id() function will return 0.